# Is 91 the only number which is both a centred cube number and a centred hexagon number?

Tags: number-theory

The proof that $6^3 - 5^3 = 3^3 + 4^3$ is the only such identity involving consecutive numbers is elementary. I'm interested to know if a stronger result is true: whether 91 is the only number that is both the sum of consecutive cubes (a centred cube number) and the difference of consecutive cubes (a centred hexagon number). (The proof either way would be well beyond me.)

Paul Stephenson

Comment: There are definitely finitely many such numbers (by [Siegel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points)...)

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html.

Comment: Also $1$ is such a number: $1=0^3+1^3=1^3-0^3$. In general, $x^3+(x+1)^3=y^3-(y-1)^3$ is an elliptic curve: $y^2-y=2x^3/3+x^2+x$.